# PHP MYSQL Prepared statements ORDER BY issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am created a prepared select query and it appears the query is not picking up the DESC or I have the bind_param structured wrong.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT t.table_id, t.table_number, s.statistic_id, s.operator, s.table_id, s.start_time, s.end_time, s.amount, s.status, s.date, s.player FROM tables AS t INNER JOIN statistics AS s ON t.table_id=s.table_id WHERE s.operator = ? AND s.status = 1  ORDER BY s.statistic_id DESC";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_SESSION['user_id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $table_id, $table_number, $statistic_id, $operator, $table_id, $start_time, $end_time, $amount, $status, $date, $player);
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)):
     echo $statistic_id; //I want to sort statistic_id as DESCENDING ORDER However, it sorts as ascending order
?>
```

Sample output i get

```
 #  Стол №  Начало  
 1  Консоль 2019-02-26 13:12:21
 2  Консоль 2019-02-26 13:12:25
 3  Консоль 2019-02-26 13:12:29 
 4  Консоль 2019-02-26 13:34:26
```

I want to out this from the last row as an example

```
  # Стол №  Начало  
  4 Консоль 2019-02-26 13:34:26
  3 Консоль 2019-02-26 13:12:29 
  2 Консоль 2019-02-26 13:12:25
  1 Консоль 2019-02-26 13:12:21
```

Am i doing this right?

Comment: Can you add some sample data, what you get from this query & whats expecting?

Comment: Please show us the code all the way from here to the execute as well, specially as you suggest you may have a problem with the bind

Comment: @Sinto Hi I want to sort my data by DESCENDING and display it

Comment: that you have already told above.

Comment: There is no obvious reason why the query you have written would not do what you want, so PLEASE show us more code so we can try and be of some use to you. ___Please remember we are not looking over your shoulder___, we only know what you show us.

Comment: Ok can you show us a few lines of the output please. The issue must have something to do with the contents of `s.statistic_id`

Comment: @RiggsFolly are you still there?

Comment: Yes I am, what can I do for you

Comment: It would be better to just paste some lines into your question as an example. Following random links can be dangerous :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly take a look please at my edited question

Comment: Is this `Консоль 2019-02-26 13:34:26` the content of `s.statistic_id` or is that 2 seperate columns?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no s.statistic_id is start from # - here

Comment: Hmmm that makes no sense? Have you tried running this query through phpMyAdmin or something like that? Does that also get the sort wrong?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah also sort gets wrong

Comment: Are you sure you are outputting `s.statistic_id` and not `t.table_id`

Comment: @RiggsFolly sure I can show you even with teamviewer if you want

Comment: Then I am stumped

Comment: @RiggsFolly will you try if i gave you credentials to my teamviewer ?

Comment: Sorry no, and you shoudl not give those out over here its not private

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh okay, anyway I have to figure it out somehow